# My list is empty after adding an object to the list

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, controller

I am coding an MVC4 C# internet application and when I save an object to a list successfully, when I get a listing of this list in another function, the list is empty.

Here is my code:

```
public class House
{
    public House()
    {
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string RoomOwnersName { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code to create and add a room to a house:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int id, Room room)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        House houseToAddRoomsTo = db.Houses.Where(h => h.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        houseToAddRoomsTo.Rooms.Add(room);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", id);
    }

    return View(room);
}
```

Here is my code to get a listing of the rooms in a house:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    RoomsViewModel roomsViewModel = new RoomsViewModel();
    roomsViewModel.HouseID = id;
    roomsViewModel.Rooms = db.Houses.Where(h => h.id == id).First().Rooms.ToList();
    return View(roomsViewModel);
}
```

After I have created a room, and added this room to a house, and I call the Index method to view the rooms for a house, the list is empty.

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework nor LinqToSql load related entities automatically

Either set them up to be eager or lazy loaded

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx (Entity Framework)

[In linq to sql how do I include the child entity with initial query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783109/in-linq-to-sql-how-do-i-include-the-child-entity-with-initial-query)